# How to uninstall VirtualBox from debian package?

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, uninstall

I installed VirtualBox by downloading the .deb file directly from their [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), however, turns out I won't actually need that program and I have no idea on how to uninstall it.

I found a couple solutions that suggested `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox` but that doesn't work since I didn't install it from apt, upon running `whereis virtualbox` I get the following directories:

```
/usr/bin/virtualbox 
/usr/lib/virtualbox 
/usr/share/virtualbox
```

Do I just delete everything from those directories or what do I do to properly uninstall the program?

Comment: @karel It doesn't work, I get the message "no packages to remove", edit: wait let me try the other solutions :) I just tried the first one

Comment: You can also just double-click the original .deb file (open it with gdebi) and wait a second. in the upper right, it'll have an option to uninstall the program.